# Getting Banana to work with Solr 4.2

Tags: solr, lucidworks, banana

I'm running Solr 4.2 and would like to try out LucidWorks Banana product.  However, when I navigate to the banana directory on my Solr server, I receive a 404 error.

I'm following the instructions from their github site [here](https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana), basically dropping the banana `src` directory into the my `SOLR_HOME\solr-webapp\webapp` directory.

I've tried modifying the `src\config.js` and `src\app\dashboards\default.json` files as suggested by the readme file to change the localhost URL to the actual server name or the IP address.  Both attempts still resulted in the 404 error.

Has anyone had luck in getting banana working with Solr 4.2?  Is it not supported on this version of Solr?  Hopefully I'm missing something really simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At LucidWorks, we have only tested Banana on Solr 4.4 and above. So, I am not sure whether all the functionality will work with Solr 4.2. However, I do know a couple of users on Solr 4.3 (who might have made some small code changes).

That said, the webapp is just javascript/html and should at least come up (maybe with errors on the dashboard, but not a 404), even without modifying config.js/default.json.

Just to confirm your process (from https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/blob/release/QUICKSTART):

```
 Copy Banana folder to $SOLR_HOME/example/solr-webapp/webapp/
 Browse to http://localhost:8983/solr/banana/src/index.html#/dashboard
```

If you dropped the src folder (and not the banana folder), then you will need to 
browse to http://solrserver.yourdomain.com:8983/solr/src/index.html#/dashboard

Comment: Thanks!  I figured out my issue, and your answer made me re-examine my configuration.  I'm going to answer my own question, but thank you for your help!  Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm accessing banana from a remote machine, so I had to update config.js and default.json...but I also want to point at something other than collection1, so I need to update those files anyway.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out thanks to Ravi's suggestion that made me re-examine my configuration.

Turns out my web app was actually running from `C:\Windows\solr-webapp`, and not `$SOLR_HOME\solr-webapp\webapp`.  I missed that my CWD was set to `C:\Windows` even though everything else was pointing to `$SOLR_HOME` directories.

Once I dropped the Banana folder into `C:\Windows\solr-webapp\webapp`, I was able to bring up the dashboard.  Now I have other errors, but that's a different set of issues.

Hope this helps someone.  TL;DR - make sure your CWD is consistent with the destination of banana.

Comment: Same Issue resolved by having a look in your main solr installation folder for the "solr-webapp" folder. No idea why but for me it ended up in "/Users/myusername/Documents/solr-5.1.0/server/solr-webapp/webapp". When I added the banana folder inside here ("/Users/myusername/Documents/solr-5.1.0/server/solr-webapp/webapp/banana") everything worked perfectly. Hope it helps someone.